# Spring Security Login: Password can be seen in the View Source

Tags: spring-mvc, spring-security, spring-security-ldap

I am using Spring security and able to logIn through my custome page with method="post" only, but not method="get", I need to get Login via method="get" so that no one can see my password in the view source.

[image]

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

To use POST you need to configure UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter manually and **not** to use `http.formLogin()`:

```
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter authFilter = new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter();
    authFilter.setPostOnly(false);
    http
    //       other configuration...
            .addFilterAfter(authFilter, LogoutFilter.class);
}
```

But you have to be aware that GET method is totally insecure - your password will be transferred through query parameter of an URL like `www.yoursite.com/j_spring_security_check?j_password=some_password`. And many and many HTTP servers log incoming URLs in their log files. So your password will eventually appear in logs which is not good at all.